# Importing URLs of Audio Enclosures

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, import

I'm importing the RSS feeds of podcasts into a custom post type with custom fields using FeedWordPress. The URLs of the audio enclosures are appended with extra information I don't need.

What I Get In My Custom Field: 
[image]

How can can I grab only the URL and not the extra info?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're working with from the image, but I'll assume newline breaks.

```
<?php

$string = "http://www.podcast.com/track.mp3
2207703
audio/mpeg";

echo "<pre>";
echo $string; // should show multiple rows
```

To grab the first line, try [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
// now grab the first line

if( preg_match ('/^(.*)$/m', $string, $matches) ){

    echo $matches[0]; // first line is the URL

}
```